# Example interpretations of rank biserial correlation?

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data, binary-data

Could anyone please suggest some reading on rank biserial correlation? I have tried to Google it but I found just a general info on its application without any any example, interpretation, etc.

Comment: Welcome to CV! You may have more luck obtaining an answer if you give a bit more detail on what you're looking for, and how the common resources you've found are inadequate. E.g., are you looking for examples of how to interpret rank-biserial correlation within a certain field?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Well, almost all the information on point-biserial correlation coefficient which is different from rank biserial correlation. What I am interested in is the coefficient explanation & examples.

Comment: I've edited your title in the hopes of attracting more potential answerers. If my interpretation is incorrect, please feel free to edit.